# /Mt and /clr not compatible

Tags: c++, clr, mt

I have been using EIGEN to solve systems of equation. the only way I was successful to compile my code is by using /CLR. 
When I try to build my project.I noticed that in order for my exe to work on other pc, I need to build it using /MT (not DLL). problem they are not compatible.
if I remove /CLR, my project wont compile, and if I leave the DLL, my exe works on other pc but gives unrealistic value.

Can someone advise on what to do. This is my first program I write. I am a mechanical engineer solving equation, please bear with me.

Ok I just search in the web, but I found that I can not build a windows form application without /CLR.

I am not sure if my target machine will have redistributed vc. is there any way to have my exe along with some dll instead? I often see this with small programs.

Comment: This is a rock-hard restriction, no point in looking for a workaround.  You **have** to build with /MD, end of story.  Just run the vc_redist installer to get the CRT installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to link to the dynamic runtime, `/MD`. The problem you have is that the other machine doesn't have that runtime installed. Solve that by simply installing, on each machine where you need to run the program, the redistributable package for your version of Visual Studio.