# My dll needs x64 version of MSVCP120.dll, but it doesn't search the System32 folder

Tags: c#, windows, dll, c++-cli

I've written a DLL, using C++/CLI, which runs fine on my Windows 7 x64 PC. Its only dependencies are VC++ (msvcr120, msvcr120_clr0400 and msvcp120) and some of OpenCV's modules (opencv_core2410, opencv_high2410, opencv_imgproc2410).

I've tried running the code that consumes this DLL on a Windows Server 2008 R2. This server has both versions (x86/x64) of MSVC++ 2013 Redist installed, and I verified that the DLLs are present in the C:\Windows\System folders.

I've tested it both through a IIS service and through a Windows Form, and in both cases it fails to find MSVCP120.dll. I checked using Process Monitor, and it looks for this file in C:\Windows\SysWoW64, C:\Windows\system, C:\Windows and lots of other folders, but not on C:\Windows\System32.

So I copied the MSVC*120 files from the System32 folder into the executable folder and it executed normally. So, how do I fix this? It is easier to just copy the DLLs, but I'm considering this wouldn't be the best practice, is there anything I should do to ensure it looks for the DLL in the right folder?

Comment: Your assumption that this is x64 code is just wrong.  Process Monitor tells you what happened, only a 32-bit process ever looks in c:\windows\syswow64.  Don't change anything, local copies of these DLLs is best.

Comment: @HansPassant The software consuming the dll is 32-bit, and my guess is it should work with 32-bit C++ Redist, usually it does work. I didn't understand why it worked with the dlls from the 64-bit one.

Comment: @HansPassant So I did try and do what you've said: I copied the x86 dlls into the binary folder and it ran, and also fixed another error I was getting somewhere else. Still, I wonder why it didn't open the dlls from the SysWOW64 folder. I'll start deploying the package with these dlls inside, even though target machines have the C++ redist installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Statically link to the VS runtimes, instead of using dynamic linking to the runtime DLLs.

for do this you can set RunTime-Library to Multi-threaded for your DLL project:

in the IDE through project settings under C/C++ > Code Generation  > RunTime Library > Multi-threaded (/MT) or (/MTd).

then compile the project and use your dll anywhere without any problems!.

Note : You should compile your project in the release mode.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I've given incomplete information. What I'm doing is a C++/CLI wrapper for a native C++ project (compiled to a .lib). I can't use /MT with the wrapper because it's incompatible with the /clr flag, which is necessary for the C++/CLI project. Also, C++/CLI projects depend on MSVC*.dll files, so I guess it wouldn't matter if I used static linking on my native project.

Comment: I've found this discussion here where someone explains why /MT and /clr are incompatible: "Considering that it is not recommended to statically linking to VC libraries and dynamically linking should be used whenever possible, it was decided to not enable /MT /CLR VS2005". Is this wrong? http://www.windows-tech.info/17/5f0fd2024b850de5.php

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is true or not ,May be I am wrong, so please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386749/mt-and-clr-not-compatible) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938539/why-is-clr-incompatible-with-mt-and-mtd-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You see I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just in doubt. I think the person at the link I posted above hasn't given a full explanation, as he hasn't said why it wouldn't be recommended. Sure, when /clr is used, that's not even an option, how could someone recommend it? But when there's no CLR, I think it would only make sense to disallow static linking if MS automatically updated MSVC on clients' machines, but I don't think they do that.